# React Native Contact on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I already tried to search for an answer here and on the internet but unfortunately, I found nothing about this.
I simply try to stock all contacts to use them after but when I try the `Contacts.getAll(err,contacts)` it instantly returns an error : **Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different**

(I'm not sure if this is relevant but after the error there is this tab in the logs :
`[[11,4,32,32,10,32,29,32],[3,0,1,0,0,0,4,0],[[],[],[59],[60,0,1619865418703,false],[],[61,0,1619865418704,false],[62,2000,1619865418706,false]],1534]`)

I checked if I had the authorization to read contacts and it tells me that I have it (in the logs there is *you can read contacts*. Here is the problematic part of my code :

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  PermissionsAndroid,
  Platform,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';
import MonBouton from './MonBouton';

const requestReadContactsPermission = async () => {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
      {
        title: 'App Premission',
        message: 'Ask to read your contacts',
      },
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log('You can read contacts');
    } else {
      console.log('read contacts permission denied');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
};

const Friends = props => {
  let [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
  const loadContacts = () => {
    Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
      console.log('contacts -> ', contacts);
      if (err === 'denied') {
        console.warn('Permission to access contacts was denied');
      } else {
        setContacts(contacts);
        console.log('contacts', contacts);
      }
    });
  };

return (
    <View>
      <MyButton
        titre="Add contacts"
        onPress={() => loadContacts()}
      />
      <MyButton
        titre="request permissions"
        onPress={requestReadContactsPermission}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

if you have any idea I gladly listen to them, I'm quite new with React and I didn't find anything about this issue. I hope I'm precise enough this is my first question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewrite the loadContacts function

```
  const loadContacts = () => {
    Contacts.getAll()
      .then(contacts => {
        console.log('contacts -> ', contacts);
        setAdresses(contacts);
        console.log('contacts', contacts);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        if (err === 'denied') {
          console.warn('Permission to access contacts was denied');
        }
      });
  };
```

getAll() returns a javascript Promise, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise